# Copy initialization with a literal

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I thought that when doing this:

```
String s1 = "hello";
```

there are 2 operations happening (e.g., as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462773/c-copy-construct-construct-and-assign-question)): (1) constructing a temporary object with the string literal `"hello"`, and then (2) copy-constructing `s1` with the temporary object.

However, when running the following code, the only printing I get is from String's constructor, and not from its copy constructor. Why?

```
static char *AllocAndCpy(const char *src_);

class String
{
public:
    String(const char *string_="");
    String(const String &other_);
private:
    char *m_str;
};

String::String(const char *string_): m_str(AllocAndCpy(string_))
{
    std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
}

String::String(const String &other_):m_str(other_.m_str)
{
    std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
}

static char *AllocAndCpy(const char *src_)
{
    size_t src_length = strlen(src_)+1;
    char *dest_ = new char[src_length]; 
    return (static_cast<char *>(memcpy(dest_, src_, src_length))); 
}

int main()
{
    String s1 = "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with or without optimization? or debug/release mode?

Comment: compiled with no optimizations: i tried `-O` and also `-O0` to `-O3`

Comment: and with `-DDEBUG`

Comment: There's a flag like `-fno-elide-constructors` or something to disable this behaviour. Lowering optimization flags doesn't normally do it.

Comment: I don't think most compilers change their behavior with regards to copy elision based on optimization levels. You have to specifically request they not do it (`-fno-elide-constructors` if using gcc or clang, for example)